Connecting Azure Container Registry resource across tenants to push ACR Images
Hello Support Community,
I am getting the error listed below while pushing ACR from one tenant to another. Please advise !
Thanks !
-- Deployment YAML:
# Push build to PME ACR using Managed Identity
      - stage: ACR_Push_PME
        displayName: "[PME] ACR Push"
        dependsOn: Build
        condition: succeeded()
        pool:
          name: tpre-buildpool
          image: tpre-release-image-linux
          os: linux
        jobs:
          - template: Microsoft.OneVet.API.OVDF/Pipelines/acr-pme-ev2-template.yaml@self
            parameters:
              JobName: ACRPushPME
              JobDisplayName: "ACR Push Job PME"
              Environment: "TPRE_DEV"

ACR Template referenced in deployment yaml
#use managed identity
              ACR: "pmedevacr"
              UseManagedIdentity: true  # Enable managed identity for ACR authentication

            # Login to ACR using Managed Identity or Service Connection based on the parameter
            - ${{ if eq(parameters.UseManagedIdentity, true) }}:
              - script: |
                  az login --identity  # Log in using Managed Identity
                  az account set --subscription ${{ parameters.SubscriptionId }}  # Set the correct subscription
                  az acr login --name ${{ parameters.ACR }}  # Login to ACR without the --subscription argument
                  displayName: "Login to ACR using Managed Identity"


WARNING: Unable to get AAD authorization tokens with message: 2024-10-05 19:02:19.608041 An error occurred: CONNECTIVITY_REFRESH_TOKEN_ERROR
Access to registry 'pmedevacr.azurecr.io' was denied. Response code: 401. Please try running 'az login' again to refresh permissions.
WARNING: Unable to get admin user credentials with message: The resource with name 'pmedevacr'
and type 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries' could not be found in subscription 'CFAR CPS DEV (3c6eede2-a8a9-4fd2-8a2e-314b4af6a3a8)'.
**ERROR: Unable to authenticate using AAD or admin login credentials. Please specify both username and password in non-interactive mode.
/mnt/vss/_work/_temp/08c3d2d4-74bd-4aa9-abc1-2fbe652a9260.sh: line 4: displayName:: command not found
**

checked support wikis
Expected output:
successful connectivity between ACR's from source to target tenant

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-faq#can-i-use-a-managed-identity-to-access-a-resource-in-a-different-directorytenant
